# Ubuntu 15.10 does not read my CD drive

Tags: mount, data-cd

I have read/tried just about every post I've seen on here but Ubuntu will not see my CD drive. When I run `sudo lshw -C disk` I get the following:

- `*-disk:0
     description: SCSI Disk
     physical id: 0.0.0
     bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
     logical name: /dev/sdb
     configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512`
- `*-disk:1
     description: SCSI Disk
     physical id: 0.0.1
     bus info: scsi@6:0.0.1
     logical name: /dev/sdc
     configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512`
- `*-disk:2
     description: SCSI Disk
     physical id: 0.0.2
     bus info: scsi@6:0.0.2
     logical name: /dev/sdd
     configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512`
- `*-disk:3
     description: SCSI Disk
     physical id: 0.0.3
     bus info: scsi@6:0.0.3
     logical name: /dev/sde
     configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512`
- `*-disk
     description: ATA Disk
     product: WDC WD5000AAKX-6
     vendor: Western Digital
     physical id: 0.0.0
     bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
     logical name: /dev/sda
     version: 1H18
     serial: WD-WCC2EJJ14651
     size: 465GiB (500GB)
     capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
     configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=4f4849fc`

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release? Is the drive older?

Comment: By mount I mean if u put a disc in it and use `mount` does our show up?

Comment: The release is in the title. I went and bought a new computer just to install Ubuntu on so I don't think  the drive is that old. and when I use 'mount' I get an error that says /cdrom don't exist.

Comment: Just for fun, what's output of `fdisk -l`? I have a hard time reading the lshw output.

Comment: Could it be a slave master issue? I see a lot of `scsi` drives.

Comment: I suggest disconnecting all drives except boot drive and cdrom..

Answer (score 1):

I found [a solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653445/ubuntu-14-04-lts-automount-cd-dvd-to-media#answer-653456) in [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com):

```
sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
```

And add this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/cdrom  /media/cdrom  udf,iso9660  user,noauto,exec,utf8  0  0
```

I'm not quite satisfied with this solution because, in previous versions of Ubuntu, the devices were mounted per user in "/etc/media/".

Any ideas?

I have three computers with Ubuntu 15.10, one with Ubuntu and two with Ubuntu Gnome. All of them have the same problem, so I think this has to be a common issue with this version. It's strange that there is no better solution yet.

Comment: It's an answer, but in my opinion it's not the best answer. It's more like a workaround.